# Android - how to avoid multiple deployment of the same .jar

Tags: android, shared-libraries

my problem is as follows: I need to develop several android apps deployed as different APKs. Each application needs a set of third-party jars. I would like to deploy these files just once.

All the approaches I have found up to now require that if I develop 5 different applications (each in an distinct APK) the ten shared 3rd party jars are deployed 5 times.

This most certainly is no good to me, how can this be avoided?

Thanks, regards

Vincenzo

Comment: are those 5x 3rd party jars doing the same task ? and difference only based on Android SDK version ? just to get the correct view to be able to help

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. The jars all do different things, i.e. they are not different versions of the same API. Specifically they allow to connect to proprietary backend systems. Android SDK version is not relevant. So if I develop several Android apps that need these jar, it would be good if such jars could be deployed just once.

Comment: so you want to use the same instance of each class of those jars in your 5 different android applications?

Comment: yes correct, I would like to have each one of those jars deployed just once and be runtime-referenced by each Android app. I come from the JEE development, so feel free to say that this does not make sense in mobile development if you think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is applicable to you .. make one application which will act as service and responds to other 5 applications. this service will represent your 3rd party jars ..

Comment: This definitely makes sense to me, generally speaking. However, this solution requires to create a thin software layer (the service) which acts as a wrapper around the 3rd party libraries. What I'm trying to achieve is simply re-use the jars across multiple applications. Can't we add the jars to a device-wide classpath folder just as you would do for instance when adding jars to an application server classpath?